# preg_replace - get tweet id from twitter status url

Tags: php, preg-replace

This is how my status url look like

```
http://twitter.com/username/statuses/303095169115357184
```

Now i would like to get the tweet id `303095169115357184` using preg_replace.

Can someone help me with regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to use `preg_replace()`.

`$id = basename($url)`